# Logstash seems not to be started when I configure elasticsearch output

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, logstash, kibana

I have this docker-compose.yml file i put below.
Actually what I need is to feed csv files using the http input plugin, that's why it's present in the configuration.

I'm testing with that simple curl line just to test that the basics work and then go on with the csv files and the rest of the configuration.

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:6.7.0
    command: bash -c 'bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-input-http && bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-output-elasticsearch && bin/logstash -e "input { http { port => 5044 } } filter { split {} csv {} } output { elasticsearch { hosts => '127.0.0.1:9200' } }"'
    links:
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 5044:5044
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.7.0
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.7.0
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"

configs:
  logstash_config:
    file: ./configs/logstash.conf

volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local
```

When I try the command below it fails as shown: (Windows 10)

```
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:5044/twitter/tweet/2' -Method Put -Body 'hello2'
curl : The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
At line:1 char:1
+ curl 'http://127.0.0.1:5044/twitter/tweet/2' -Method Put -Body 'hello ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

But if works when I use this docker_compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:6.7.0
    command: bash -c 'bin/logstash -e "input { http { port => 5044 } } filter { split {} csv {} } output { stdout { codec => rubydebug} }" && bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-input-http && bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-output-elasticsearch'
    links:
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 5044:5044
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.7.0
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.7.0
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"

configs:
  logstash_config:
    file: ./configs/logstash.conf

volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local
```

I launch the same command and now it works.

```
 curl 'http://127.0.0.1:5044/twitter/tweet/2' -Method Put -Body 'hello2'


StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : ok
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Content-Length: 2
                    Content-Type: text/plain

                    ok
Forms             : {}
Headers           : {[Content-Length, 2], [Content-Type, text/plain]}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {}
ParsedHtml        : mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass
RawContentLength  : 2
```

I desperately need to pass the data to elastic
Any ideas on whats wrong are welcomed

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you do not have to install the logstash plugins. Batteries are included. Plugins can be listed: `bin/logstash-plugin list`

Next, make use of docker service discovery. Your service `elasticsearch` is resolvable from within you logstash container. Localhost within your container resolves to - *container localhost*, not *host localhost*.

```
HOST localhost =! CONTAINER localhost (in bridge mode)
```

A working docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:6.7.0
    command: bash -c 'bin/logstash -e "input { http { port => 5044 } } filter { split {} csv {} } output { elasticsearch { hosts => [\"elasticsearch:9200\"] } }"'
    networks:
      - elastic-net
    ports:
      - 5044:5044

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.7.0
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    networks:
      - elastic-net
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.7.0
    networks:
      - elastic-net
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"

networks:
  elastic-net:

configs:
  logstash_config:
    file: ./configs/logstash.conf

volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local
```

*links* is a docker legacy construct. Instead use the *networks* construct.

Best of luck.